# Редакция неясного фрагмента предложения

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, стилистика

Во многих странах **исключаются из числа страхуемых депозиты лиц и организаций,** имеющих возможность получать информацию о финансовом состоянии банка и обеспечивать соблюдение им рыночной дисциплины.

Не понимаю выделенный фрагмент. Кто исключается из числа - лица и организации?

Как отредактировать предложение?

Контекст.
При создании системы страхования депозитов необходимо, исходя из поставленных перед системой задач, определить круг депозитных инструментов, которые предполагается обеспечивать страховой защитой. Во многих странах исключаются из числа страхуемых депозиты лиц и организаций, имеющих возможность получать информацию о финансовом состоянии банка и обеспечивать соблюдение им рыночной дисциплины. **К числу таких лиц и организаций относятся банки,** государственные органы, инвестиционные, аудиторские компании, а также члены советов директоров и руководители банков.

Из контекста следует, вроде лица и организации исключаются. Но понять это очень трудно.

Может так?

Во многих странах исключаются из числа страхуемых депозиты лиц**а** и организац**ии,** имеющ**ие** возможность получать информацию о финансовом состоянии банка и обеспечивать соблюдение им рыночной дисциплины.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Не понимаю выделенный фрагмент. Кто исключается из числа - лица и
>   организации?

Депозиты.

> Во многих странах исключаются из числа страхуемых депозиты лица и
>   организации, имеющие возможность получать информацию о финансовом
>   состоянии банка и обеспечивать соблюдение им рыночной дисциплины.

А вот тут у вас уже этакий швондеризм "Кто на ком стоял?". 
Не **"депозиты"** же имеют возможность получать что-то?!
А "лица и организации" это не множественное число, а родительный падеж, требует "имеющих возможность". Впрочем, все равно плохо, явно хуже исходного.

> Как отредактировать предложение?

Исходный вариант вполне корректен и понятен, править ничего не надо. Но если уж кто-то очень настаивает (автор, редактор, заказчик, внутренний голос), то просто добавьте слово "депозитов" и чуть измените порядок слов.

***Во многих странах из числа страхуемых депозитов исключаются депозиты
лиц и организаций, имеющих возможность получать информацию о
финансовом состоянии банка и обеспечивать соблюдение им рыночной
дисциплины.***

Comment: Ваш вариант намного яснее.

Answer (score 2):

> Кто исключается из числа - лица и организации?

Нет. Исключаются депозиты, которые принадлежат этим лицам и организациям. Другими словами, такие депозиты нельзя застраховать. Далее в контексте поясняется, какие лица и организации [желающие застраховать свои депозиты] попадают под это ограничение. Всё корректно.

> Может так?
>
> Во многих странах исключаются из числа страхуемых депозиты лица и
>   организации, имеющие возможность получать информацию о финансовом
>   состоянии банка и обеспечивать соблюдение им рыночной дисциплины.

А вот этот вариант совсем никуда не годится. Смысл этого предложения невозможно понять. Вы хотели поставить запятую после слова "депозиты"? Но депозиты не могут получать информацию. Или объясните, пожалуйста, другими словами, что имелось в виду.

Comment: Запятая стоит после слов "лица" и организации". следовательно, в моей редакции получается, что информацию имеют лица и организации.

Comment: @plotnikov.tosha2016 *"депозиты лица и организации"* – прочитайте внимательно этот фрагмент. Его невозможно расшифровать.

Comment: депозиты лица и организации" -да, я имел в виду, депозиты страхуют лица и организации. Т.е. они исключаются.

Comment: Исправил так. Во многих странах депозиты лиц и организаций, имеющих возможность получать информацию о финансовом положении банка и обеспечивать соблюдение им рыночной дисциплины, исключаются из числа страхуемых....

Comment: Может, будут лучше варианты.

Comment: Этот вариант мне нравится чуть больше оригинального.

Comment: Исходный вариант последователен и прост по своей схеме: "кое-где нельзя застраховать то-то (перечислено и оговорено)". В изменённом же виде сначала идёт обширное описание с перечислением, а под конец (к разочарованию читателя) как бы говорится: так вот, со всем этим ровно ничего не происходит!

Comment: @Alex_ander, исходный вариант тяжело читается.

Comment: *исходный вариант тяжело читается* - дело привычки. Зависит от целевой аудитории, насколько могу судить, случайный человек такой текст читать просто не будет.

Comment: *Исправил так* - это лучше грамматически, но очень длинное определение перед пациенсом (объектом)  не способствует пониманию. То есть проблема восприятия, о которой говорит Alex_ander, только усиливается.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, ничего менять не надо (кроме субъективного отношения автора вопроса).

Дополнение.

Возникли сомнения по поводу слов "имеющих возможность... обеспечивать соблюдение им (банком) рыночной дисциплины." Дисциплину соблюдают или нет, а как можно обеспечивать ее соблюдение и кто это делает? А еще круче, имеет возможность обеспечивать соблюдение дисциплины? Что это за возможность такая? Набор слов. Думаю, имелись в виду лица, имеющие доступ к информации о соблюдении рыночной дисциплины и/или контролирующие соблюдение рыночной дисциплины.

Comment: *Думаю, имелись в виду лица, имеющие доступ к информации* - а вот не уверен. Я так понял, что здесь подразумеваются "лица, имеющие возможность обеспечивать...".   - ревизоры, контролеры, аудиторы... Они конечно, имеют указанную информацию, но не только этим славятся, Они реально могут вмешаться в процесс, пусть и не на уровне прямого управления, но по факту вынесения решения.

Answer (score 2):

Во многих странах исключаются случаи страхования депозитов лиц и организаций, имеющих возможность получать информацию о финансовом состоянии банка и обеспечивать соблюдение им рыночной дисциплины.